# BCC Support Address not showing up in debug logs in Salesforce

Tags: email2case, service

I setup Email to case in my Salesforce Org with two emails. I need to filter to which email the customer replied and handle this in logic accordingly.

So i sent an email to one of the two emails setup from my email client,only filling out the BCC option. I saw that the case was created with the sent email. But in the debug logs the BCC address of the email shows as null.

Can someone help with the use case on why can't I capture BCC email address in debug logs. Even though it created the case.

Comment: What does the Case's child `EmailMessage` object look like? EmailMessage is created by SFDC for email2Case operations

Comment: Same issue here. I have assignment rules working successfully on To and CC addresses, but it seems there is no way to capture the Bcc even through coding. It always seems to be empty, but of course it isn't because a new Case got generated by the Email-to-Case functionality.
Salesforce support said that Bcc address is not supported, but first why to expose it in the Email Message object if it is not working? second why it creates a case if it receives emails in Bcc?

Comment: Anyone got the answer for this one ?